# How to run a batch script if local IP matches a set range?

Tags: batch-file, ip, compare

I am trying to match my local IP and see if it matches a set range. If it matches, I need to run a batch script.

e.g. If my IP matches the range `172.16.32.1 - 172.16.32.254`, then a batch script needs to run, which is located on a file share.

Comment: what exactly you mean with range? First two/three digit to be the same?

Comment: Hi npcomaka,
apologies i should have made it clearer.
what i`m trying to do is that.
If i am the client PC which is running this batch script
I will first check for my own PC IP
If my IP is in the 10.12.90.x segement, i will go to this fileshare and run the script and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ipconfig | find /i "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.32." >nul 2>nul && (

  call some_script.bat 

) || (

  echo not in range

)
```

Comment: thank you.
So i guess i can incorporate if-else statement with the above code?

Comment: @AWSLearner - there is if-else statement.It just using conditional execution - http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

Comment: @AWSLearner - You can use a "classic"  if-else by checking the errorlevel.`FIND` sets errorlevel to 1 if astring is not found - http://ss64.com/nt/find.html